TanStack `useInfiniteQuery()` - how to update the `initialPageParam`?
Tanstack Query V5.
My page parameter is a Date object, it starts at the current time (new Date()) and lists data in reverse order from "now" up until a limit of rows, then the next page's pageParam is calculated using the date from the last row of the previous page.
This all works well, but when the user hits the "refresh" button, I want to "reset" the query and update initialPageParam so that the user can see the latest data.
The refetch() function is not useful, because it just re-issues whatever queries were already issued (depending on how far the user scrolled through pages).
My workaround to this is to model the startDate as react state that is defaulted to the current time on first render. I then include the startDate in the queryKey for the call to useInfiniteQuery().  When the user hits the refresh icon, I do a setStartDate() with new current time.
This works, but it's a bit janky because the entire query gets thrown away immediately.  Including the start parameter in the query key means status is  re-set to pending and all the old data is thrown away immediately when the user presses the refresh icon.
That means the screen "flashes" through the "pending" state (just a spinner because there's no data to display) and then re-displays the first page.
Is there any direct support in the infinite query API for re-setting the start initialPageParam?
Ideally, I'd like to keep the old data displayed (with some UI feedback indicating a refresh is happening), then the page would be updated based on the new data and the old page data can be discarded (remembering that because the cursor is time-based, old page data would be out of date because the messages will be spread across pages different if new data has been added to the beginning of the query).

const getNextPageUntil = (lastPage: ListDeliveredMessagesResultV1) => {
  if( lastPage.messages.length === 0 ){
    return undefined;
  }

  const lastForwardAt =
    lastPage.messages[lastPage.messages.length - 1].forwardedAt;
  return addSeconds(lastForwardAt, -1);
};

export function DeliveredMessageContent(){
  const api = useAuthApi();
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());

  const fetchDeliveredMessages = async ({pageParam}: {pageParam: Date}) => {
    return await api.mail.listDeliveredMessages({until: pageParam});
  };

  const {
    data, error, status,
    fetchNextPage, hasNextPage,
    isFetching, isFetchingNextPage,
  } = useInfiniteQuery({
    queryKey: ['deliveredMessagesInfinite', startDate],
    queryFn: fetchDeliveredMessages,
    initialPageParam: startDate,
    getNextPageParam: getNextPageUntil
  });

  /* This does what I want (reset the start-time of the query to current-time)
    so that user can see any new messages that have arrived.
    As opposed to refetch(), which just re-issues the queries from the original
    value of initialPageParam.
    But it's janky - by including the startDate in the query key, it means
    we get an entirely new query in a completely "reset" state, so instead
    of showing the old results while the refresh is happening, the content
    resets and the user sees the SmallPageSpinner instead.  It's particularly
    ugly when the query runs fast and the pages just quickly "flashes" the
    spinner while the query is running. */
  const handleRefresh = () => {
    console.log("refresh");
    setStartDate(new Date());
  };

  if( status === 'pending' ){
    return <SmallPageSpinner message={"loading delivered messages"}/>;
  }
  if( status === 'error' ){
    return <CompactErrorPanel error={error}/>;
  }

  const messages = data.pages.map(page => page.messages).flat();

  return <LargeContentMain>
    <ContainerCard title={<>Delivered mail</>}
      action={
        <RefreshIconButton onClick={handleRefresh} refreshing={isFetching} />
      }
    >
      <Messages messages={messages}/>
      <LoadMoreButton canListMore={hasNextPage && !isFetchingNextPage}
        listMore={() => fetchNextPage()}>
        <ButtonLabel isLoading={isFetchingNextPage}>
          Load more messages
        </ButtonLabel>
      </LoadMoreButton>
    </ContainerCard>
  </LargeContentMain>;
}


